# Go program loads a DLL compiled from Go code error

Tags: dll, cgo

Go program loads a DLL compiled from Go code
What should I do  Thank you.
go version 1.18
windows 10
Sometimes, after calling the operation, it can run normally for the first time. If it runs again, it will report an error, and then it will always report an error

Errors are reported as follows

```
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0x67b21ff5]

goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
runtime.throw({0x67bdb25b?, 0xc0000240c0?})
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:1047 +0x65 fp=0xc00003b9c0 sp=0xc00003b990 pc=0x67b44085
runtime.sigpanic()
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/signal_windows.go:249 +0x213 fp=0xc00003ba08 sp=0xc00003b9c0 pc=0x67b572f3
runtime.heapBitsSetType(0xb0b245?, 0x300000002?, 0x100c000034000?, 0x1943b4f9628?)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/mbitmap.go:921 +0x3d5 fp=0xc00003bb30 sp=0xc00003ba08 pc=0x67b21ff5       
runtime.mallocgc(0x10, 0x67bc4ba0, 0x1)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1050 +0x64d fp=0xc00003bba8 sp=0xc00003bb30 pc=0x67b1c58d       
runtime.newobject(0x14?)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1192 +0x27 fp=0xc00003bbd0 sp=0xc00003bba8 pc=0x67b1c927        
os/exec.Command({0x67bd43ec, 0x8}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0?})
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/os/exec/exec.go:274 +0x38 fp=0xc00003bc28 sp=0xc00003bbd0 pc=0x67b9f6d8
main.main()
        D:/code/test_dll/main.go:68 +0x2c fp=0xc00003bc60 sp=0xc00003bc28 pc=0x67ba336c
main.RunHacking8(...)
        D:/code/test_dll/main.go:60
_cgoexp_b07154bc348b_RunHacking8(0x0?)
        _cgo_gotypes.go:39 +0x27 fp=0xc00003bc70 sp=0xc00003bc60 pc=0x67ba33c7
runtime.cgocallbackg1(0x67ba33a0, 0xc000026000?, 0x0)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:316 +0x2c2 fp=0xc00003bd40 sp=0xc00003bc70 pc=0x67b13f82
runtime.cgocallbackg(0xc000034000?, 0x300000002?, 0xc000034000?)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:235 +0x105 fp=0xc00003bdd0 sp=0xc00003bd40 pc=0x67b13bc5
runtime.cgocallbackg(0x67ba33a0, 0x6b639ffadf, 0x0)
        <autogenerated>:1 +0x36 fp=0xc00003bdf8 sp=0xc00003bdd0 pc=0x67b702d6
runtime: g 1: unexpected return pc for runtime.cgocallback called from 0xb542a0
stack: frame={sp:0xc00003bdf8, fp:0xc00003be20} stack=[0xc00003a000,0xc00003c000)

runtime.cgocallback(0xb02a8b, 0xb57e20, 0xbd4940)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:994 +0xd7 fp=0xc00003be20 sp=0xc00003bdf8 pc=0x67b6e097
```

Comment: func main() {

 dll := syscall.NewLazyDLL("recar.dll")
 f := dll.NewProc("RunHacking8")
 f.Call()

}

Comment: You cannot load multiple instances of the Go runtime in the same process.

Comment: @Recar please show you main.go .

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem because my dll calls another dll which cannot be called again